# docker compose always building the Dockerfile thus it does not depend on db

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile which is actually building a maven spring boot project. My docker-compose.yml is bellow

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=calero
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    links:
      - "db:db"
  redsparrow:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    links:
      - "db:db"
    depends_on:
      - db
volumes:
  db:
    driver: "local"
```

And the Dockerfile is this

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app 
RUN mvn clean package

FROM tomcat
COPY context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
COPY tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
COPY tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
COPY --from=build /app/target/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

But what I am facing here docker-compose always try to build the redsparrow before spinning up the mySQL container and mvn clean package trying to access the database as it is not up then, the build does not get succeed.

I think I am missing something so that the spring boot app (redsparrow) should always get built after the database container is up.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `docker-compose.yml` configuration doesn't provide the feature you outline in your question. The image of the service containing the `build: .` option will always be built in isolation. However, you could achieve what you want in other ways.

To sum up, the service at issue is a dockerized Java/Maven/Spring-Boot project that relies on a dockerized MySQL database, and accessing that database is required to build you project with `mvn clean package`, probably due to the presence of integration tests in the `test` Maven phase.

To overcome this, I see two possible approaches (the first approach being less standard and less easy to implement than the second one; so I'll elaborate mostly on the latter):

1. You could rely on the [docker-maven-plugin](https://dmp.fabric8.io/) to spin the MySQL container directly from Maven. See also [this blog article](https://blog.philipphauer.de/dont-use-in-memory-databases-tests-h2/). The practical issue here will be that the `docker` commands are not directly available inside the considered Docker container, unless you rely on [DinD](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/) (Docker-in-Docker).
2. A simpler approach would involve adapting the tests themselves rather than changing the docker setup:

   - this is closer to standard conventions assuming `mvn test` (triggered by `mvn package`) targets unit tests, while `mvn verify` (relying on the [failsafe](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) Maven plugin) targets integration tests, involving external databases or services;
   - still, if you want to keep all the same a number of unit tests involving database operations, you might want to use an in-memory database engine such as [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), which is often used in the context of Spring Boot unit tests (see e.g. [that tutorial](http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-h2-in-memory-database));
   - then, you could move your integration tests in an extra docker-compose service, following the approach outline in [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-continuous-integration-testing-environment-with-docker-and-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-14-04) and [that article](http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2018/02/service-testing-docker-containers.html), for example:

     ```
     integrationtest:
         build: ./integrationtest
         command: ./wait-for-it.sh -h db -p 3306 -s -t 150 -- mvn verify
         depends_on:
           - db
     ```

As an aside, note that the `links:` property is now [deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links).
Note also that the above `.yml` excerpt relies on [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) because the `depends:` property only waits for dependencies' containers to be started, not to be fully ready.